# using Jenkins dynamic shared lib into pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I can't figure how to define a dynamic shared library, and use it into my pipeline:

```groovy
myLib=library (identifier: 'lib@master', retriever: modernSCM(
    [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
        remote: 'https://mygit.orga.com/git/ORGA/Jenkins-libs.git',
        credentialsId: 'aaaaaaa-8f3f-4e3c-vvvvvvv-6c77351e7872',
        includes: '*',
        excludes: 'test'
    ]))

pipeline {

  agent {

    node(){
      label("linux&&!master")
    }
  }


  tools {
    jdk "JDK1.8.0_45"
    maven "MVN339"
  }
  stages{
    stage("test lib"){
      steps {
        script {

          myLib.a.b.c.Utils.sayHelloTo("Guillaume")
          log.info("test lib")
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

At runtime it fails with :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Utils
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
```

Any ideas of what is wrong? I can't find any info on dynamic shared lib tutorial on the net.

Edit : adding the library tree :

```
src
--a
  --b
    --c
      Utils.groovy
```

`Utils.groovy` content:

```groovy
package a.b.c

class Utils {

    def sayHelloTo(String name) {
        script.echo("Hello there $name")
    }
}
```

Thanks guys,
Guillaume

Comment: Can you share a minimal example of the `Utils` class, folders, package, and what not to reproduce?

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically

Comment: @mkobit : edit done with lib tree

Comment: @MattSchuchard : already read it many times :(

Comment: after 30 more tests : if i move my Utils class into vars/ instead of src/a/b/c and if i remove the package reference, everything is ok:

there is clearly something wrong while scanne src folder and loading packages inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't explain the CNFE you are getting, but there is definitely a couple of issues with this code.

- The `sayHelloTo` method is not declared as `static` and yet, it is being called as one.
- The `script.echo` doesn't seem valid, as I can't see `script` being a valid name here.

If you want to use this as a static function, then change the function like this

```
<     def sayHelloTo(String name) {
>     static sayHelloTo(def steps, String name) {
```

The only change to the call is to pass `this` (which should refer to pipeline steps):

```
<           myLib.a.b.c.Utils.sayHelloTo("Guillaume")
>           myLib.a.b.c.Utils.sayHelloTo(this, "Guillaume")
```

If you instead want to keep it as an instance method, then you still need to accept steps:

```
<     def sayHelloTo(String name) {
>     def sayHelloTo(def steps, String name) {
```

However, the call would change like this:

```
<           myLib.a.b.c.Utils.sayHelloTo("Guillaume")
>           myLib.a.b.c.Utils.new().sayHelloTo(this, "Guillaume")
```

In all the cases, the `echo` call would change as:

```
<         script.echo("Hello there $name")
>         steps.echo("Hello there $name")
```

Comment: sorry for the delay
you post really helped me to change my way to realize this
everything is OK now

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Guillaume, how about accepting my answer?